# Different registration id for same device after uninstalling the app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I was under the impression that the GCM registration is always the same for the same combination of device, application and application version.

But now I realized that it always changes when I uninstall the application and then install it again.

**The Problem**

My app create a profile for each device the user uses. So if a user install the app, uninstall it and install it again, the app will have two profiles for the same user in the same device.

I am currently storing the registration id in the shared preferences to update the profile if the registration id changes, but when the app is uninstalled the shared preferences are lost.

**The Question**

Is there anyway to preserve the registration id after the app is uninstalled?
Any other idea of how can I update one of the existing profiles (identified by the old registration id) instead of creating a new one?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Google Backup Services to preserve data of application even after uninstall

Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#BackupKey

```
  OnBackup() // can save GCMId

  OnRestore() // can retrive the same
```

Comment: This data is used on install on all subsequenty devices and therefore a really, really bad idea for saving GCM IDs (which need to be unique for each device)